# How to order the .txt files

Tags: python, sorting, format

I have made an arithmetic quiz that asks you ten questions and the class you are in. The user will put there name in and either enter 1,2 or 3. It will then ask the user the ten questions, but at the end it will save the data which is the name and the scores of the user to  a .txt file called Class1Score, Class2Score or Class3Score.

Here is my code that shows the arithmetic quiz:

```
import time
import math 
import random
print("Title:Arithmetic Quiz")
print("*************************************************************")

print("This program will ask you to complete the arithmetic quiz.")
print("The program has 10 questions. You will recieve feedback after.")
print("____________________________________________________________"
while True:
    UserName = input("What is your name?:")
    if not UserName.isalpha():
        print("Error!Please enter your name using letters. ") 
        continue
    else:
        break
ClassSelection= input("Please enter what Class you are in?:1, 2 or 3")
ClassChosen=0
while ClassChosen==0:
    if ClassSelection=="1":
        ClassChosen=1
    elif ClassSelection=="2":
        ClassChosen=1
    elif ClassSelection=="3":
        ClassChosen=1
    else:
        print("You must write 1, 2, or 3.")
        ClassSelection=input("Enter the class you are in")


print(UserName," welcome to the Arithmetic Quiz.")
print("____________________________________________")
print("The quiz will begin in 3 seconds")
time.sleep(2)
for i in range(0,3):
    print (3 - i)
    time.sleep(1)
print("Begin!")
print("*****************************************")


#___________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________  
RecentStudent= [0,0,0]
def MathsQuiz():
    score=0
    for questionNum in range(10):
        Num1= random.randint (1, 10)
        Num2= random.randint (1, 10)
        Symbol = ["+","-","*"]
        Operation = random.choice(Symbol)
        RealAnswer= int(eval(str(Num1)+Operation+str(Num2)))

        print("Please give an answer for:", Num1, Operation, Num2)    
        UserAnswer = int(input("Enter your answer here:"))
        if UserAnswer == RealAnswer:
            score = score + 1
            print("You are correct! :D")
            print("_______________________________________________")
        else:
            print("You are incorrect! :( ")
            print("The answer was", RealAnswer)
            print("________________________________________________")
    print()
    print("__________________________________________________")
    print("Thank you for completing the quiz!")
    print("Your Score is loading")
    import time
    time.sleep(2)
    print(UserName,"In this test you achieved",score,"/10")
    print()
    del RecentStudent[0]
    RecentStudent.append(score)
    print("Your three most recent scores are:",RecentStudent)
    print("********************************************************")
def Resit1():
    Resit1=input("Do you want to resit the test? Yes or No?:")


    if Resit1== "Yes" or Resit1=="yes":
        MathsQuiz()


def Resit2():
    Resit2=input("Do you want to resit the test? Yes or No?:")


    if Resit2== "Yes" or Resit2=="yes":
        MathsQuiz()
        print("Quiz Finished")


#____________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________________        
MathsQuiz()
Resit1()
Resit2()
if ClassSelection=="1":
    Class1 = []
    Class1.append("Student: ")

    Class1.append(UserName)
    Class1.append("Latest 3 Scores: ")
    Class1.append(RecentStudent)


    file = open("Class1Scores.txt", 'a')


    file.write(str(Class1))


    file.write("\n")
    file.close()

elif ClassSelection=="2":
    Class2=[]
    Class2.append("Student: ")

    Class2.append(UserName)
    Class2.append("Latest 3 Scores: ")
    Class2.append(RecentStudent)


    file = open("Class2Scores.txt", 'a')

    file.write(str(Class2))



    file.write("\n")
    file.close()


elif ClassSelection==3:
    Class3 = []
    Class3.append("Student: ")
    Class3.append(UserName)
    Class3.append("Latest 3 Scores: ")
    Class3.append(RecentStudent)


    file = open("Class3Scores.txt", 'a')


    file.write(str(Class3))

    file.write("\n")
    file.close()
```

What I wanted to do after the scores are saved in the file is  ask the user what data they would like to see. The data that the user can see is the highest, result the lowest result,the average score,the names in alphabetical order and the highest scores from each class. I used dummy values that would save the last three scores of the user to the file in the format 1,2,10.

Here is an example of what the output is to the .txt file when I save the scores to it:

```
['Student: ', 'clive', 'Latest 3 Scores: ', [0, 0, 0]]
```

This is the format it saves as I dont know how to sort the results into the data types of the new program sorter.

Comment: You may want to read the [PEP8 python style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), anyone that has to read your code will thank you for it.  As written now, your code is almost unreadable.

Comment: Sorting a file is so 1980s have you thought of using a sqlite? If you don't want to do that,, the easiest would be to read the entire file into memory and pass it to sorted with a suitable key function

Comment: @e4c5 could you please help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to persist the data in a file, you need to choose a file format that is capable of serializing the data.  The two most common ones for python are `json` and `pickle`

```
import json

data = ['name', 'John Doe', 'scores', [1,2,3]]

# Serializes data and write it to file
with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'w') as f:

    json.dump(data, f)

# Read the data back in
with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    read_data = json.load(f)

print(read_data)
# ['name', 'John Doe', 'scores', [1,2,3]]
```

Comment: Hey where would this code go and what would this sort?